# Disputed audit review - non code based answer

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

This is the first time I've ever posted on Meta, but I am really curious about this review task audit that got me:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/16450599

I don't know anything about the OP's question on OS X, that's not my software of choice. The answer, while it did not have code, did seem to discuss what might be causing the error which was a non-scripting solution. While reviewing I can't always vouch for the accuracy of the information, but I can look and see if it at least APPEARS to be a legitimate attempt to answer the question.

Am I way off on this? Am I supposed to be reviewing first answers for accuracy of content? Isn't that what the voting system is for?

Comment: From the "answer" - _"Sometimes this error occur because your application code was trying to connect to the database and could not connect"_ - So where is the part they explain the reason for that? And simply restarting the server is not an acceptable solution - Perhaps as a comment, but certainly not as anwer. You can always skip a review if you don't understand the topic, it's better than guessing

Comment: *Am I supposed to be reviewing first answers for accuracy of content?* Yes, for first posts you are. Down voting is an option in that queue. It doesn't look OK, the question isn't even using or mentioning MySql. Yes, it answers an question, still isn't OK.

Comment: In support of what @AlonEitan said: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip

Comment: Sure I can skip a review, and I do, but there are literally tens of thousands of tags on SO. No one can possibly be deeply knowledgeable on all of them. In this case, the OP had a connection issue. The answerer was using MySQL as a related example to illustrate the point. I thought it could have been a BETTER answer, but I didn't think it was a TERRIBLE answer that deserved to be flagged.

Comment: @SandPiper Please note that you can `filter` reviews by tags - You'll see a link in the title when you're reviewing posts, so just filter by tags you're familiar with

Comment: I was reviewing this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue and even though it is about the LQP queue, I think the same argument applies in this case. The answerer made a legitimate attempt to answer the question, even if he didn't provide as useful of an input as he could have.

Comment: Please, use filters. If you are going to review, do so in posts that you can, well, review them with full confidence that you are going to do a good job.